# How can I get Windows-10 to remember my default app?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin

I have cygwin installed on my new Windows-10 PC and I have a file "foo.bash" on my desktop that I need to be able to double-click on and have c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exec open it (foo.bash is a shell script being interpreted by bash.exe). On my previous PCs I simply double-clicked the program, browsed til I found/selected bash.exe, clicked the "always use this app" button and from then on double-clicking on foo.bash would always open it using bash.exe.

On my new Windows 10 laptop I initially had the same experience but then after a couple of days I created a file named "bar.bash" and was surprised to get prompted for what type of app to open it with. bash.exe was listed so I selected that, clicked the "always open with" again and that was fine but then when I had to open it again later I found that the "always open with" hadn't stuck. So I repeated and could not get Windows to remember to open that ".bash" extension file bar.bash with "bash.exe"

So I went back and double clicked on the original "foo.bash" and it opened with bash.exe. I tried changing it's "open with" to Notepad to see if that would stick and it didn't AND then I found I could no longer get bash.exe to stick either.

So now every time I double-click on a file with a ".bash" extension I have to click on bash.exe to open it. I have tried associating the extension with the app from the file properties, from the Settings menu, and everywhere else that any web page I can find tells me will work and none of them work - I 100% CANNOT get Windows 10 to remember to open ".bash" files with "bash.exe".

I also followed the steps at https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-file-association-windows/ to delete the references to a ".bash" extension from the registry and that changed the popup prompt for which app to open the file with but after once again selecting bash.exe and "always open with", I was back once again to having to repeat the process every time I open the file.

Does anyone have any real ideas on how to do this? I assume it'll involve some arcane procedure to edit registry entries or something else that I REALLY don't want to be messing with but I've exhausted all of the "normal" ways that this should work from a user perspective.

Comment: Can we get a working example here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @user3440639 what kind of "working example" do you have in mind for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! In a flash of inspiration I restarted Windows in Safe Mode (a chore in itself these days - see https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10) and then right-clicked on foo.bash, searched for bash.exe again, selected it and now after rebooting back out of safe mode the association with "bash.exe" is still in place for all my ".bash" files.

So the trick is - go into safe mode to permanently associate the file suffix with the app.